# Can't mount ntfs drive anymore ($VOLUME_INFORMATION attribute not found in $Volume)

Tags: linux, rsync, ntfs, usb, gparted

I have a external hard drive with ntfs partition and it isn't accessible or mountable anymore. Last thing I did was a rsync copy to that usb drive. I still can see the ntfs partition with **gnome-disks** but I'm not able to mount it.

With **gparted** and **ntfsfix** (ntfs-3g package) I get the same error message:

```
$VOLUME_INFORMATION attribute not found in $Volume
```

I also checked the smart data from the drive which is OK (No errors logged, thresholds not nearly reached)

I also checked the hard drive with a second linux client (same behavior) and a windows client (doesn't recognize even the ntfs partition, diskmgnt says it contains a 'raw' partition)

When I'm using **testdisk** I'm able to see the partition and also list the folders and files. When I want to write the partition details it looks like it worked (no error message from testdisk) but even after a reboot I can't mount my drive and the error message is still the same.

I wonder how can I access the data again without the need to copy it somewhere else (don't have the storage for it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't restore the partition/hard drive itself but were able to restore *all my files* with **testdisk** to a second drive with the same size.

I used this 'forced' disk switch to get finally rid of my last ntfs partition and started new with a luks encrypted ext4 file system!